# Copy PDF files from Sharepoint folder to FTP using Power automate

Tags: sharepoint, ftp, power-automate

I am new to power automate. I have a requirement to copy files from sharepoint folder to FTP using power automate.

Step 1: Created "When file is created in folder" (sharepoint) -> Provided sharepoint address and folder
Step 2: Create File( FTP) -> provided connection information

I have provided FTP details but it is failed to create connection and it says "the remote name could not be resolved. ClientRequestId:0d0b38ab-af93-4d9e-91ec-d97dd33c068a"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ahKC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the whole ftp endpoint like `ftps://waws-xxxxxxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot` as "**Server Address**" in your FTP connector.

Remove `ftps://` at the beginning of ftp endpoint, just use `waws-xxxxxxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot` instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I am able to connect now. But not able to copy the files. The error says "The FTP quota has been exceeded" when i upload manually.